# UPS requirements for server

Tags: ups

I have a DL380 Gen9 server, and I would like to get a UPS for it so that when power outage happens, the server will be up at least for a minute. The server has two PSU, each 500W. I actually got a UPS (1500VA, power factor 0.6), but it could not keep server up when power outage happened. Server shut down immediately. Shouldn't 1500VA be fine for 500W server? I am confused. What is that I am missing to consider? By the way, I run 6 VMs on server as my virtual lab.

Your help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that the battery in the UPS is good?

Answer (score 2):

A 1500VA UPS is more than sufficient for your server, which likely only uses 200 Watts or less while it's running. You can see the realtime power usage in the ILO4 interface of the server.

You should investigate why your UPS did not function properly during the outage. This is easy to test, since you just remove the utility power or utilize the *Test* button on the UPS.

---

Can you provide details on what type of UPS you purchased?

Some UPS solutions may have power ports that are not protected by battery power.

For instance, this APC device only has 2 power ports that are available for battery backup.

[image]

Did you connect everything properly?

Comment: I use "Mercury Elite 1500Pro" which has 4 output on its back, but they aren't tagged as battery or surge. I haven't tested this UPS with a desktop PC, since I don't have one yet. But I tested it with an HP switch, and it works (switch stays online). My only guess now is that the UPS I am using is kinda cheap compared to many server grade UPS, so something, some functionality, doesn't exist on it.

Comment: Call the manufacturer and explain your situation. This should work.